# Rails: Paypal configuration file and figaro environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I´m using the gem '[paypal-sdk-adaptivepayments](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-ruby)' to integrate Paypal in my Rails app. The configuration file is paypal.yml:

```
development:
  # Credentials for Classic APIs 
  username: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_USERNAME_DEV"]
  password: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_PASSWORD_DEV"]
  signature: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_SIGNATURE_DEV"]
  app_id: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_APP_ID_DEV"]
  http_timeout: 30
  # Mode can be 'live' or 'sandbox'
  mode: sandbox
test:
  <<: *default
production:
  <<: *default
  #mode: live
```

Cause this information is secret I want to use another gem called '[Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)' that externalize this variables. I used this for another configuration files in my app but it doesn´t works with 'paypal.yml'. I know that doesn´t works because when I put the real information in the paypal.yml file it works.

```
development:
  # Credentials for Classic APIs 
  username: *******@yahoo.com
  password: *******
  signature: ******
  app_id: ******
  http_timeout: 30
  # Mode can be 'live' or 'sandbox'
  mode: sandbox
test:
  <<: *default
production:
  <<: *default
  #mode: live
```

Has anyone used Figaro with this file? Is there any other option to "secretize" this information in Rails?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, what you should do is replace your yaml config file with a config.rb file:

```
#config/initializers/paypal.rb
PayPal::SDK.configure(
  username: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_USERNAME_DEV"],
  password: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_PASSWORD_DEV"],
  signature: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_SIGNATURE_DEV"],
  app_id: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_APP_ID_DEV"],
  http_timeout: 30 
)
```

Then define these variables in a yaml file such as application.yml:

```
#config/application.yml
PAYPAL_CLASSIC_USERNAME_DEV: yourpaypalusername
PAYPAL_CLASSIC_PASSWORD_DEV: yourpaypalpassword
PAYPAL_CLASSIC_SIGNATURE_DEV: yourpaypaysignature
PAYPAL_CLASSIC_APP_ID_DEV: yourappid
```

Lastly assuming you are using git for your version control, go into your gitignore and tell it to ignore the yaml file with your secret info:

```
#.git_ignore
/config/application.yml
```

This will properly keep your environment variables out of your code base when you push it to github or other git repo.

Edit: To use different environment keys you merely specify the keys for different environments in your yaml file:

```
#application.yml
production:
  PAYPAL_CLASSIC_USERNAME_DEV: yourpaypalusername
  PAYPAL_CLASSIC_PASSWORD_DEV: yourpaypalpassword
  PAYPAL_CLASSIC_SIGNATURE_DEV: yourpaypaysignature
  PAYPAL_CLASSIC_APP_ID_DEV: yourappid
```

That being said, I highly suspect what you are doing is a violation of 12factor best practices. This yaml file is not a part of your application - when you push your code up to a server like Heroku, this file is not supposed to go with it. The yaml file with your keys should only ever exist on your local machine. It should not exist in Github, nor on your production server. To read more about this, check out this link: http://12factor.net/config

So how do you tell a server like Heroku what these config variables are? This will vary based on what service provider you use, but is typically done via the command line tools or through an admin management page. e.g., for Heroku you would run:

```
heroku config:set PAYPAL_CLASSIC_USERNAME_DEV=putyourusernamehere
```

Comment: How do you do it for pro credentials? Like this:if Rails.env.development?
 PayPal::SDK.configure(
   username: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_USERNAME_DEV"],
   password: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_PASSWORD_DEV"],
   signature: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_SIGNATURE_DEV"],
   app_id: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_APP_ID_DEV"],
   http_timeout: 30 
 )
else
 PayPal::SDK.configure(
   username: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_USERNAME_PRO"],
   password: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_PASSWORD_PRO"],
   signature: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_SIGNATURE_PRO"],
   app_id: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_APP_ID_PRO"],
   http_timeout: 30 
 )

end

Comment: I updated my response. I believe you may not fully understand how Figaro works. Please let me know if my update helps :)